# Save input user in Edittex

Tags: java, android, textbox, save

Good morning, I need help,
I´m new using Java in Android development and need to save user input in a textbox without needing a button to trigger it.

Could someone give an example please?

Comment: If my answer below work for you, please accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

You will need a TextWatcher, since you do not want to trigger a click event
[Here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html)! is a good example of TextWatcher control,

once you get families to TextWatcher, you can save your value either in a SharedPreference (Local tiny storage) or in a Databse, Refere [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240243/shared-preference-android-storing-data)! for storing and retrieving values from SharedPreference

Comment: Thanks for atention Bhavik , I will look the code and try!

Comment: @rd7 I have given the link in my answer, did you check them? they are very clear and understandable if you go through, your English is much better

Comment: yes Bhavik im see is very simple I need to copy all code to my Project and test today ,maybe tomorow i will have a answer.

Comment: @rd7 hope you get success, if not, contact me

Comment: Dont work yet ,when i input text in the edittext the app show error and restart, here my code in xaml:

Comment: <EditText
            android:id="@+id/t1"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="45.0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="#FF81ADEE"
            android:saveEnabled="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:editable="true">

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

Comment: remove android:editable="true" &  android:saveEnabled="true"  from your EditText

Comment: EditText input;
    EditText output;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        output = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t1);
        input.addTextChangedListener(watch);
    }

Comment: @rd7   please do not post your code in comments, if you are facing errors, make a separate question for it

Comment: @rd7   send me the complete code @ bhavikmehta5491@gmail.com

Comment: Right! i will send you in 10 minutes.